# Print output when executing public01, public02,

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -g -O0 -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow \
-pedantic-errors -fstack-protector-all 
PROGS = public01 public02 public03 public04 public05 public06 shell_jr

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(PROGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROGS) a.out

$(PROGS): shell_jr.c
public0%:
    shell_jr < public0%.in > output
    cat output
```

Whenever public0X is entered, the output of shell_jr.c when it is run with input coming from public0X.in should be displayed. The public0% tag is my attempt at making this happen. However, there are 3 problems. First, I can only have public0%.in as a dependency. That can be avoided by copy pasting separate commands for public01, public02, ... Second, when I do that and execute make, the command is immediately executed. How do I make sure that command is not executed until I type public01 and press enter?

Comment: Note that your `cat` commands ignore the standard input redirection because you supply a file name (`shell_jr`) on the command line.  Did you mean `>` instead of `<`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, but I have edited the makefile to account for the fact that cat ignores anything past the file name, and now there is a new problem.

Comment: `$*` in a rule body will be replaced with whatever matched the `%` in the rule head.  See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)

Comment: What is the error that is caused by `shell_jr < public01.in > output`?  You may need to specify the path to the program, as `./shell_jr < public01.in > output`.

Comment: @pat added the error. The error is the same if you use ./

Comment: @pat The error was in the file shell_jr.c and I didn't notice because segfault stops any print statements from executing. That error is gone now but the main problems still remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, I can only have public0%.in as a dependency.

I take this part to be asking about how to express in the recipe the correct name for the input file corresponding to the chosen target.  The `%` of a pattern rule is expanded only in the target and prerequisites, not in the recipe, but in *any* `make` recipe, the automatic variable `$@` represents the complete target name being built.  Since the wanted input name is formed by appending the suffix `.in` to the target name, it can be expressed as `$@.in`.

Additionally, you do not name the `public0%` targets as `.PHONY` (unlike `clean` and `all`), but your rule for them does not actually create them, either.  If you are trying to both create and display these files, then you can also use `$@` to direct the output to the wanted file.  Otherwise, you should mark these targets, too, as `.PHONY`.

Furthermore, if it your intention to (re)create these files regardless of whether anything has changed, then omitting the input files from the prerequisite list is appropriate.  Otherwise, however, naming the input files as prerequisites will help `make` to skip needlessly regenerating the `%public0%` files.

> Second, when I do that and execute make, the command is immediately executed. How do I make sure that command is not executed until I type public01 and press enter?

`make` is not interactive.  If you want to specify a particular target or targets to build, instead of the default, then you express them as additional arguments on the `make` command line:

```
make public01
```

But I think what you're trying to get at may be a different problem than what you actually said.  Your default target will build all of the targets named in `$(PROGS)`, and where prerequisites do not require otherwise, GNU `make` running in serial mode will attempt to build the targets in the order in which they are named.  Your `public0%` all depend on the `shell_jr` program, but they do not designate it as a prerequisite.  (They *do* name `shell_jr.c` as a prerequisite, but that's not actually a direct dependency, and designating it as one does not serve a useful purpose.)  Therefore, *`make` will attempt to build all of the `public0%` targets before attempting to build `shell_jr`*.

The correct thing to do here is to express the right dependencies.  This version does that, on the assumption that the `public0%` are intended to be actual built files:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -g -O0 -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow \
    -pedantic-errors -fstack-protector-all 

PROGS = shell_jr
OUTPUTS = public01 public02 public03 public04 public05 public06

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(PROGS) $(OUTPUTS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROGS) $(OUTPUTS)

# shell_jr is built according to a built-in rule (as was already the case)

public0%: public0%.in shell_jr
    shell_jr < $@.in > $@
    cat $@
```

Note that this will rebuild (and display) the `public0%` files only if their corresponding input files have changed or if `shell_jr` needed to be rebuilt.  If you want them to be built and displayed even when nothing has changed then you can add a target with no prerequisites or recipe, and make it a prerequisite for the `public0%` rule:

```
public0%: public0%.in shell_jr FORCE
    shell_jr < $@.in > $@
    cat $@

FORCE:

.PHONY: FORCE
```

The `FORCE` target will be considered to have been rebuilt every time `make` runs, thus triggering the `public0%` targets to be rebuilt.

Comment: I did not realize the purpose of .PHONY since up until now I had been creating makefiles by copying previously given makefiles and modifying them. I intended the results of running shell_jr.c with public01.in, public02.in, ... to not be displayed until I executed public0X (and by execute, I meant entering public0X, not make public0X), so I took your code and added public0% to .PHONY. However, executing make still runs shell_jr on all the input files.

Comment: Actually, I might be asking too much of you. My habit was to run make and then run the executables public01, public02, ... separately. In this case, all I have to do is type "cat public0X" instead of public0X.